# Spring boot gradle build fails

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, heroku

When i try to build the project i am getting this error (while deploying to heroku). Its my first Spring boot app and honestly i can't find any solution to this issue. My Jdk is v.17

```
remote:        A problem occurred configuring root project 'demo'.
remote:        > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
remote:           > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.1.
remote:             Required by:
remote:                 project : > org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:3.0.1
remote:              > No matching variant of org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.1 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.6' but:
remote:                  - Variant 'apiElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.1 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
remote:                      - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8
remote:                      - Other compatible attribute:
remote:                          - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')
remote:                  - Variant 'javadocElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.1 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
remote:                      - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
remote:                      - Other compatible attributes:
remote:                          - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
remote:                          - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
remote:                          - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')
remote:                  - Variant 'mavenOptionalApiElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin-maven-optional:3.0.1 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
remote:                      - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8
remote:                      - Other compatible attribute:
remote:                          - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')
remote:                  - Variant 'mavenOptionalRuntimeElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin-maven-optional:3.0.1 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
remote:                      - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
remote:                      - Other compatible attribute:
remote:                          - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')
remote:                  - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.1 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
remote:                      - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
remote:                      - Other compatible attribute:
remote:                          - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')
remote:                  - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.1 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
remote:                      - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
remote:                      - Other compatible attributes:
remote:                          - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
remote:                          - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
remote:                          - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')
```

EDIT:

Here is the build.gradle file configuration. Perhaps some dependency is not compatible?

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation group: 'com.opencsv', name: 'opencsv', version: '5.7.1'
    implementation group: 'org.modelmapper', name: 'modelmapper', version: '3.1.1'

}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: It looks like your configuration is setting Java 8 as the target, instead of Java 17. Can you share your `build.gradle`? Or check for any properties with `8` or `1.8` there.

Comment: Updated the post with the file. I couldn't find anywhere v8 or 1.8 :\

Comment: The `build.gradle` looks correct. Then my only guess would be that your configuration for heroku to use Java 17 didn't apply, because Heroku docs say the default Java version is 8: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support#specifying-a-java-version

Comment: Yes this worked, i have missed that in docs. Thank you !

Answer (score 9):

If you are using InteliJ you need to go to File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle and change the Gradle JVM to be the 17.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The Java version being invoked may not match.

You might check version output from `java --version`  and any java environment variables, such as `JAVA_HOME` to make sure it matches JDK v17.
Also, make sure the java being executed is a JDK installation and not just a java runtime.

I was getting this error on GitHub actions when running `ubuntu-latest` which at the time uses JVM 20.

I explicitly configured JDK 17, and the error was resolved.

Example GitHub action config -

```
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest 
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          distribution: 'temurin' # See 'Supported distributions' for available options
          java-version: '17'

      - name: Build Jar
        run: ./gradlew build
```